# Merge two columns in a specific order

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Sheet with about 1000 rows. I need to merge two columns so that

```
A1 B1
A2 B2
A3 B3
```

Becomes

```
A1
B1
A2
B2
A3
B3
```

and so on.

Comment: The before and after you've shown in your post is exactly the same. You'll always receive the best and most efficient help if you share a link to a sheet, even if that sheet only has a short set of representative data. Be sure in sharing such a link that you set the share permission to "Anyone with the link can edit."

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief descriptiono of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the undocumented `flatten` function

```
=flatten(A1:B3)
```

[image: how to use the Google Sheets flatten function]

Comment: Outstanding! Worked perfectly. Much Thanks.

Comment: You should **also** [accept the answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) so others can benefit as well. *"Outstanding! Worked perfectly. Much Thanks."* Glad I could help.